# gmail integration in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to create an app in which I want to integrate Gmail through which user can get their emails in app. So how can I do this? Can anybody help me?

Comment: It would have been helpful if the question was framed with 1) This is what I have followed 2)Which among these is good way to <question> 3) This is my code and <question>. It is always better to try out and then ask. It is easier to help and understand for us then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this Project

http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/